# How do I apply Macro/ VBA code in the all worksheets for all workbooks in a folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply one code to all my worksheets in a folder. This is the code I use for one workbook and it can only function in one workbook therefore even if I shared it to another workbook it will only apply to the workbook that has the code. How can I change to make it work? This is the one that I tried but it was not able to run.

```
If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
  folderName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If

'Create a separate Excel process that is invisibile
Set eApp = New Excel.Application:  eApp.Visible = False

'Search for all files in folder [replace *.* with your pattern e.g. *.xlsx]
fileName = Dir(folderName & "\*.*")
Do While fileName <> ""
    'Update status bar to indicate progress
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & folderName & "\" & fileName

    Set wb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(folderName & "\" & fileName)
                  
                Cells.Select
                    With Selection.Font
                        .Name = "Arial"
                        .Size = 10
                        .Strikethrough = False
                        .Superscript = False
                        .Subscript = False
                        .OutlineFont = False
                        .Shadow = False
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
                    End With
                         
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False 'Close opened worbook w/o saving, change as needed
    Debug.Print "Processed " & folderName & "\" & fileName
    fileName = Dir()
Loop
eApp.Quit
Set eApp = Nothing
'Clear statusbar and notify of macro completion
Application.StatusBar = ""
MsgBox "Completed executing macro on all workbooks"
```

I have no basic in VBA coding, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it works, but it would still be helpful if anyone could make the one I initially posted works. Thank you

```
Sub LoopFormat()
    Dim wb As Workbook, MyPath, MyTemplate, MyName
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    MyPath = "C:\Folder\" 
    MyTemplate = "*.xlsx"
    MyName = Dir(MyPath & MyTemplate)
    Do While MyName <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyName)
            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                ArialForAll
            Next ws
        wb.Close True
        MyName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Sub ArialForAll()
    
    With ws
      Cells.Select
        With Selection.Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 10
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two changes you could make that may help your original code:

fileName = Dir(folderName & "\*.xlsx")

wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

Note that these suggestions were noted in the comments, so, documentation is important to read, though it's not always helpful.